# How to hide "Launching application" dialog in clickonce

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have an application exe that i wrapped in clickonce application. Created a console application project in C#. I run the application inside like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "AppTest.exe";  
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.Start();
}
```

I copied the files to the web server and then go to the url/publish.htm created automatically by the clickonce. I can see everything is run as i want but i want to hide the "Launching Application" dialog and windows shell that is opened for a split second as well.

How do i do that?